# SSRS Sort a column by closest to a value

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

Working in SSRS, and I need to have a column that sorts the whole table based on a value closest to a number. Example

```
col1      col2
240       14
762       20
78        8
97        5
```

I need to have COL2 sorted by the number closest to 7. Below is what I expect to see.

```
col1      col2
78        8      (1 away from 7)
97        5      (2 away from 7)
240       14     (7 away from 7)
762       20     (13 away from 7)
```

I'm running a sql 2014 query on the backend to get my values. I dont really want to add another column to the query if I can help it.

Thanks for looking and I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tablix properties select sorting and use this expression 
abs(7- Fields!col2.value).

Comment: Thanks Nirup! Thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test(col1 INT, col2 INT);

INSERT INTO test(col1, col2) 
values(240,14),
(762,20),
(78,8),
(97,5);

SELECT *, CASE WHEN col2-7 < 0 then (col2-7) * -1 else col2-7 END as orders
from test
order by orders
```

Comment: Thank you Jignesh. I'd rather not make another column in the SQL query, but if I end up doing that I wlll mark you as correct. Thanks again for helping.